# How to change component places on click?

Tags: angular

What i want when user click on some button to change place for that component. I want to put some component on first place. Can i achive that? Any suggestion?

So if i have something like this:

```
<default-component></default-component>
<first-component></first-component>
```

So on click to be like this:

```
<first-component></first-component>
<default-component></default-component>
```

Is that possible to do?

Comment: Yes it is, with the flex display. You have a property called order, that gives the elements an order when you use `display: flex`. Just add `[style.order]="myVariableOrder1Or2"` to both of your components

Comment: You can use Bootstrap's `push` and `pull` classes combined with Angular's `NgClass` directive. http://ageekandhisblog.com/bootstrap-3-change-stacking-order/ If you need help writing code, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

create one variable for that and display like that.

```
<first-component *ngIf="isClicked"></first-component>
<default-component></default-component>
<first-component *ngIf="!isClicked"></first-component>
```

> change a value of isClicked variable (click)=`"onClicking"`

**component**

```
onClicking(): void {
this.isClicked = !this.isClicked;
}
```

Comment: i want to change place not to hide component

Comment: @None ngIf does not hide instead it renders or not. This is the most convenient solution in angular mvc

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, OP has no need to remove components from DOM, he simply needs to change places of component A with component B and this can be done just by using CSS and Angular's `NgClass` directive.